# Can't set color of URL in webview

Tags: html, objective-c, uiwebview

I am currently struggling with a simple problem: I was trying to set the link color in my webview, but it has no effect:

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div style='padding: 0px 20px; font-size:16px;font-family:HelveticaNeue-Light; a:link {text-decoration:none; color:#009fe3; } a:visited { text-decoration:none; color:#009fe3;}; color:#fff;>%@<div>",urlString] baseURL:nil];
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: did u try running the html code outside and see if it works or not ? try loading the html file instead of loading a plain string

Comment: try change URL color in JavaScript, and apply it like ` [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"script"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily the link color was originally set with a unique color in my HTML string, so I ended up overwriting the hex color code:

```
NSString *copy = [urlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"#2E2EFE"withString:@"#009fe3"];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:copy baseURL:nil];
```

It may be a workaround, but it works.